# display adsense when ajax post is done

Tags: google-adsense

I have a main page that I want to keep ad free, unless a visitor submits a form on the page. In that case I would like to display an Ad on the page.

I only want to display that Ad once and it will stay there until the visitor leaves.

Now, I read quite some posts on here that this may be a violation to the T&C of Google and/or that there's no adsense for Ajax (fyi: I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161806/desperately-need-a-solution-for-adsense-that-works-with-ajax), [also this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435391/refresh-a-div-that-has-a-google-ad-inside-it#441425), [this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394594/how-to-force-advert-to-show-on-ajax-loaded-page-adsense) and quite some other posts as well as the Google T&Cs).

I feel this should not be a violation, cause I might as well display the Ad immediately upon loading of the page and since I'm keeping it static after that I'm not doing any reloading or anything.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly its not a matter on how you 'feel' about Google's T&C's. These are what all webmasters agree to upon signing up too, there are many reasons why Google does not want advertisements in Ajax.

It is worth mentioning that there is many other advertising networks to consider that allow Ajax advertisements, but be warned that Google has patented algorithms that detects ad placement and can actually effect your rankings if its considered above the fold or anywhere which they consider impacts user experience, I believe they are constantly improving this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

With your initial page load you can load your Adsense Add in a div which is hidden.
When they post the form, just make the div visible.